# pre-commit hook failing for a Python project

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit-hook

I have a `Python` project that when I try to commit (through miniconda) with:

```
$ git add -A && git commit -m `test`
```

I get the following failure:

```
(base) D:\machinelearning.com-python>git commit -m 'test'
[WARNING] Unstaged files detected.
[INFO] Stashing unstaged files to C:\Users\anon/.cache\pre-commit\patch1570560215.
Trim Trailing Whitespace.................................................Passed
Check for added large files..............................................Passed
Check python ast.........................................................Passed
Check JSON...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check for merge conflicts................................................Passed
Check Xml............................................(no files to check)Skipped
Check Yaml...........................................(no files to check)Skipped
Debug Statements (Python)................................................Passed
Fix End of Files.........................................................Passed
Fix requirements.txt.................................(no files to check)Skipped
Mixed line ending........................................................Passed
Flake8...................................................................Passed
isort....................................................................Failed
hookid: isort

Files were modified by this hook. Additional output:

Fixing D:\machinelearning.com-python\scripts\train_model.py

[INFO] Restored changes from C:\Users\anon/.cache\pre-commit\patch1570560215.
```

The last line failed.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Given the output, it looks like the imports in that file aren't sorted properly -- it should have fixed them automatically for you.  If you run `git status` and/or `git diff` it'll show what is not staged and what changed

You'll then `git add` those changes and then commit again

Note that generally when working with `isort` via `pre-commit` you'll also want to include [`seed-isort-config`](https://github.com/asottile/seed-isort-config#usage-with-pre-commit) such that third party imports are detected properly

disclosure: I am the author of `pre-commit` and `seed-isort-config`

Comment: README says _`isort` when run in isolation is not the best at determining what dependencies are third party_ - can you elaborate please, either here or in README? How is `isort` detecting 3rd party dependencies and why isn't it always working as expected?

Comment: it ~essentially tries to import them

Comment: singIt helps - for me just closing and opening the commit window and re-staging solved the pre-commit issues.

Answer (score 3):

for me i used the black profile and it worked.

on `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/PyCQA/isort
    rev: 5.12.0
    hooks:
      - id: isort
        args: ["--profile=black"] # <-- this one
```

Comment: I had added the `profile = "black"` line to my `pyproject.toml` but I forgot to run `pre-commit install`, which made the changes take effect. Thanks for your answer!